# WPF DataGrid - How to move keyboard focus to newly added row after tab press

Tags: wpftoolkit, wpfdatagrid

WPF DataGrid add a new row if we press tab on last column of last row. But after adding the new row, the focus is moved to top row of the grid. How can we make sure that the focus is moved to the first column of new row?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try something like

```
this.SelectRowCell(this.Items.Count - 1, 0);
```

But I'm not sure if that will set the focus too. If not then try the following:

```
DataGridCell cell = this.GetCell(this.Items.Count - 1, 0);

if (cell != null)
{
    cell.Focus();
}
```