# How do I set keyboard focus to the Add Row after adding a row

Tags: wpf, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I have a `XamDataGrid` (version 2011.2) in a WPF application, when a user has tabbed off of the "Add New" row I need the focus to return to the first cell of the Add New row so they can enter another record, the default behaviour keeps the focus on the record that has just been added.

I have tried to use `DataPresenterCommands` to move the focus or to find a way to set `myGrid.Records.DataPresenter.ActiveCell` but haven't had any success.

I need the same functionality as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2645027/wpf-datagrid-how-to-move-keyboard-focus-to-newly-added-row-after-tab-press) but for Infragistics' XamDataGrid.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Yanko Nikolov](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/72483/367018.aspx#367018) on the Infragistics support forum for finding a solution (which I had somehow missed in my search for a answer).

The solution is to add this code to the preview key down event of the data grid.

```
private void xamDataGrid1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
     {
         Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
         {
             CellValuePresenter.FromCell(xamDataGrid1.RecordManager.CurrentAddRecord.Cells[0]).Editor.StartEditMode();
         }), DispatcherPriority.Background, null);
     }         
}
```